# Search scala list for something matching a property

Tags: java, scala

What is the idiomatic scala way to do this?  I have a list, and want to return a "Y" if I find something that matches some conditions, else a "N".  I have a solution that "works", but I don't like it...

```
def someMethod( someList: List[Something]) : String = {

someList.foreach( a =>
  if (a.blah.equals("W") || a.bar.equals("Y") ) {
    return "Y"
  }
 )
  "N"


}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are saying here. Do you mean to say that all elements should either be "W" or "Y" in order to return "Y", and that it should return "N" otherwise?

Comment: No, I just want to find 1 match then do a Y.. else a N if no matches

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simples:

```
if (someList.exists{ a=> a.blah == "W" || a.bar == "Y"}) 
   "Y"
else 
   "N"
```

Comment: If you're looking for 'idomatic', then I would suggest using == instead of .equals(...).

Comment: Ta. I was just cut and pasting the condition from the question. it's always possible equals doesn't do straight string comparison...

Answer (score 8):

```
def condition(i: Something) = i.blah.equals("W") || i.bar.equals("Y")

somelist.find(condition(_)).map(ignore => "Y").getOrElse("N")
```

or simply

```
if (somelist exists condition) "Y" else "N"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Something has a blah member.

```
def someMethod(someList: List[Something]): String = 
  if (someList forall { a => a.blah == "W" || a.blah == "Y" }) "Y" else "N"
```

Comment: Plus doesn't forall mean it must return true for all values? I only want 1 match

Comment: == does the Right Thing for strings in Scala.

Comment: I'm still a little puzzled on what you want to achieve, but you are saying that you expect "Y" if there is at least one Something with a blah value of either "W" or "Y", then simply replace forall with exists.

Comment: I guess the OP wants to use `exists` instead of `forall`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4)

(l.find(x => x == 0 || x == 1)) match { case Some(x) => "Y"; case _ => "N"}
res: java.lang.String = Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Something` can pattern match, e.g. when it is a case class like...

```
case class Something(blah:String, bar:String)
```

... you can write...

```
 def someMethod(someList: List[Something]) = someList.collect{
   case Something("W",_) | Something(_,"Y") => "Y"}.headOption.getOrElse("N")
```